# How to get all the SharePoint web parts that are there inside a page and not inside a web part zone

Tags: web-part, powershell, web-part-zone

I need some C# or powershell script where I need to list down all the web parts that are defined inside a page and not inside a web part zone.

I tried with GetLimitedWebPartManager, but that API, will return only the web parts which are defined inside a web part zone.

But I need an logic, which will give me all the web parts which are not created inside a web part zone.

-Premchand

Answer (score 1):

```
WebPartManager wpm = WebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(this.Page);
int webPartCount = wpm.WebParts.Count;
```

Comment: I cannot use WebPartManager as I wont get Page reference, as I am doing a console application. Its not a web application and its a simple console application and I just need to prepare some report

Comment: Use SPLimitedWebPartManager.WebParts . This should give you all the weparts in the page. Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartmanager_properties.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the [WebPartManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpartmanager%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class.  Have a look at the sample code. It uses the GetCurrentWebPartManager method.